# Upload image using URL (CollectionFS package)

Tags: meteor, collectionfs

Have anyone tried to upload images with CollectionFS package but using URL (some image link from different domain) instead of input field.
Would be grateful for any hints. There must be some way

I see it like this:

1. Insert link into field
2. Fire server method and get image data
3. Somehow put data inside CollectionFS upload proccess (don't know how yet)

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/wiki/Insert-One-File-From-a-Remote-URL

Comment: omg! Seems like it is exactly what I need. I will post an answer if it will work. Thank you very much!